# Celery - Chaining remote callbacks

Tags: python, celery, distributed

I have three Celery tasks that run on three different servers respectively.

- tasks.send_push_notification
- tasks.send_sms
- tasks.send_email

I want to setup a workflow such that if sending push notification fails, I should try sending sms. And if sending sms fails, I should send email.

If those 3 tasks and their code base was on the same server, I would have followed [the example on chained tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#the-primitives) and done something like

```
from celery import chain
from tasks import send_push_notification, send_sms, send_email
import json
# some paylaod
payload = json.dumps({})
res = chain(
    send_push_notification.subtask(payload),
    send_sms.subtask(payload),
    send_email.subtask(payload)
)()
```

But the tasks are kept on 3 different servers!

I have tried

```
# 1
from celery import chain
from my_celery_app import app
res = chain(
    app.send_task('tasks.send_push_notification', payload),
    app.send_task('tasks.send_sms', payload),
    app.send_task('tasks.send_email', payload)
)()
# Which fails because I am chaining tasks not subtasks
```

and

```
# 2
from celery import chain, subtask
res = chain(
    subtask('tasks.send_push_notification', payload), 
    subtask('tasks.send_sms', payload), 
    subtask('tasks.send_email', payload)
)()
# fails because I am not adding the tasks on the broker
```

How can this be done?

**Update:**
I can do it using `link` NOT `chain`.

```
from celery import subtask
res = app.send_task(
    'tasks.send_push_notification', (payload, ),
    link=subtask(
        'tasks.send_sms', (payload, ),
        link=subtask(
            'tasks.send_email', (payload, ),
        )
    )
)
```

There is a lot of nesting. And because I actually need to create a database driven workflow, it will be complicated to create it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Why not handle it in your tasks,

```
def push_notification_task(payload):
    if not send_push_notification(payload):
        sms_notification_task.delay(payload)

def sms_notification_task(payload):
    if not send_sms_notification(payload):
        email_notification_task.delay(payload)

def email_notification_task(payload):
    send_email_notification(payload)
```

Moreover, `chain` will execute all of your tasks in the given order, whereas you want next task to run only if first failed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using `chain` because I want to follow the `chain of responsibility` design pattern. Your solution will not work because those three tasks / their code bases are not at one place. They are situated remotely.

Comment: Basically my end goal is creating a database / configuration driven workflow on actions like push notification, sms, email, etc.

Comment: No matter where are the code bases for all the tasks, if your Celery workers are using same Broker then this approach should work, as `.delay`  will add task to broker queue and worker will pick it from queue after completing current task.